# Как разбить строку в массив?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка (tsv файл) такого вида:

```
"текст" "1" "45"    ""  "текст"
```

Как с помощью `preg_split()` разбить такую строку в массив?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$str = '"текст" "1" "45"    ""  "текст"';
$arr = preg_split('/"\s+"/', trim($str, '"'));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```